# Cannot play a mp4 video inside a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to play a mp4 video inside a collection view, but couldn't succeed. The methods i tried are:

**Method 1:**

```
let html = "<video playsinline controls width=\"100%\" src=\"\(url)\"> </video>"
cell.webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
cell.webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

**Method 2:**

```
cell.webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: source)!))
```

Result:
[Video doesn't load and shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gEi4.png)

Comment: Have you enabled NSAppTransportSecurity?

Comment: Yes, i have enabled.

Comment: please share video url

Comment: This url is playing in our site. But not working in mobile.
http://test.creatrixcampus.com/uploads/doc/binaryOctalHex_1526459737.mp4

Comment: why you use HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below code,

```
let html = "<video width=\"100%\" controls> <source src=\"http://test.creatrixcampus.com/uploads/doc/binaryOctalHex_1526459737.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>"
```

**UPDATE**

```
let html = "<iframe src=\"http://test.creatrixcampus.com/uploads/doc/binaryOctalHex_1526459737.mp4\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>"
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

Below is the output for the same,

[image]

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Video was not loaded. Buffering for a long time.

Comment: No its not working for me
                  
let html = "<video width=\"100%\" controls> <source src=\"http://test.creatrixcampus.com/uploads/doc/binaryOctalHex_1526459737.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>"
 cell.webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

Comment: @DeepikaUdayakumar please find updated answer, it is working perfectly

Comment: there should be some mistake from your end, please cross verify

Comment: I am trying to play video in a collection view inline. i tried your code in a sample project separately too. still its not working. Is there any other settings to be done?

Comment: I get this following error <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None

Comment: No i tried in sample project and it gives proper output and I posted image also from iOS simulator

Comment: Hi, Its working now fine. In iOS version 10.3 its really working good, but in iOS 11 and above is not working properly. Can you give some idea to resolve this? Please. Thanks in advance. I ll share the video link for clarification

Comment: No It is working on iOS 11 also, simulator screenshot is from ios 11

Answer (score 0):

why you use HTML to embedded Video in , you can use native

just Set  `Allow Arbitrary Loads`  to `YES` in your `info.plist` file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

And in code Test it

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
class ViewController: UIViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://test.creatrixcampus.com/uploads/doc/binaryOctalHex_1526459737.mp4")!
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerController.player = videoPlayer
        avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width:300, height: 300)
        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
        videoPlayer.play()

    }
}
```

[image: check image]

Comment: i'm sure its working i test it me self just check your `plist file`

Comment: i tried your code in a sample project separately too. still its not working. Is there any other settings to be done?

Comment: i share image for result just check it, share what you have

Comment: This is the code i wrote.             

if let videoURL = URL(string: source) {
       let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
       let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
       avPlayerController.player = videoPlayer
       avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width:cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        cell.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
        videoPlayer.play()
 }

Comment: Source url make sure that ur correct try url you set above

Comment: `if let videoURL = URL(string: source)`  this line make sure  `source` is correct URL

Comment: check plist file  , also test this url `http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v`

Comment: Hi, Its working in sample project. But while i implement inside my actual project, it is not working.

Getting error as:

AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None

Comment: Do you have any idea on this

Comment: Clear and build

Comment: It working now, due to network issue it was not working earlier. But i cant able to pause or play the video.

Comment: deeepika yes I told you this

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I tried disconnecting the network connection. and connected a different one then it worked.

Comment: Y i am not able to pause and play even the video time?

Comment: `avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false`  just set to true

Comment: i will check for you

Comment: Thank you so much.